# Ajax+Jquery Javascript running very slowly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, internet-explorer

On a website I'm designing a user searches for hotels in a city, and results are returned as xml then formatted through ajax/javascript/jquery.

The results are displayed almost immediately in Chrome or FF, but in Internet Explorer (I've tried ie6 and ie9) the results take almost a minute to be displayed.

Running the developer tools in IE states that 99% of execution time is spent in function "getElementsByTagName"  which is called almost 200,000 times, however I'm unaware of how to fix this if it is the issue.

The page in question is [beta.hotelsweep.com](http://beta.hotelsweep.com) and the function being called on search is:

```
//summarized version of the function
$.get(url, function (xmlResponse) {
    $('#results').empty();
    var exception = $("Exception", xmlResponse);
    if (exception.size() > 0) {
        var error = "<h2>We were unable to complete your request</h2>";
        $('#results').html(error);
    } else {
        $('#numResults').html($("resultsNumber", xmlResponse).text() + " hotels found <br>");
        var resultsHtml = "<div id='results_list'>";
        //set googlem map to center
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng($("avgLat", xmlResponse).text(), $("avgLong", xmlResponse).text()), 9);

    // Loop through response, creating <li> for each hotel
        $("Hotel", xmlResponse).each(function () {

            var bookLink = $('affiliateLink', this).text();
            var address = $('fulladdress', this).text();
            var stars = $('stars', this).text();
           resultsHtml += 'Hotel Stars: ' + stars;
        });

    //put html into results div
        $('#results').html(resultsHtml);
    }
});
```

Comment: The javascript engine Chrome uses is much faster then that of IE's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was something to do with the document mode. In quirk mode, the javascrit wasn't even fully executing.

Adding this to the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

or

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Made Internet Explorer execute as expected. I don't fully understand what is happening, but if you find your javascript executing incorrectly only in IE it could be to do with the document mode.

Comment: i will tommorrow, clicking the accept tick tells me "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"

Answer (score 0):

You can't really fix this issue.  getElementsByTagName isn't indexed in older versions of IE.  You can use element id lookups instead (avoid $("Exception"), $("avgLat"), etc).

If that's not feasible, you can add a script on the server to render the results to HTML.

Comment: Could you link any resource you've learned from, getElementsByTagName isn't indexed in older versions of IE? Sounds strange.